# ADS-B - Measure distance from position on ground to an aircraft

Tags: altitude, ads-b

I have a docking station for autonomous drones in the field. It is equipped with a Raspberry Pi, an 1090 MHz ADS-B stick, and it knows it's geometric position from a previously done precise measurement. This station needs to maintain a cylindrical "flight security zone" around itself. Whenever an aircraft breaches this zone, security measures are taken. Furthermore...

- the zone's exact dimensions are not known yet, but we can assume a diameter of around 5km and a height of around 200-300m.
- within the zone, the measurements of aircraft positions should be "as precise as possible". Outside the zone, I don't really care
- the measurements need to work for every aircraft, optional messages only certain aircrafts send are not an option.

**My Question in a nutshell**

How can I measure the distance between an aircraft and myself, and what would be the most precise way to do it?

**My ideas so far**

I have used [dump1090](https://github.com/antirez/dump1090) to receive ADS-B messages from the stick, which returns them in raw- or SBS-1 format.

The horizontal distance from my station to the aircraft should be deductable in sufficient precision from the ADS-B messages, I guess. An SBS-1 message, for example, contains the already calculated WGS84 coordinates.

The vertical distance is a bigger problem. As I understand, ADS-B works with pressure altitude referenced to standard pressure. That leaves me with two options:

- Integrate a barometer into my setup and correct the aircraft's altitude with reference to my local pressure.
- ADS-B also mentions a message with GNSS height (Type Code 20-22), but I can't seem to find any info about when to expect it. Is is completely optional, is it mandatory below transition height...?

Are my general assumptions correct? Are there other possibilities?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**

Note that if there are rare and "unusual" occurances where planes might not identify themselves via ADS-B, like military machines that don't use ADS-B for reasons of camouflage, or planes with broken transponders, then these occurances can be ignored. I realize that, with just an RPi and an ADS-B stick, my capabilities are limited. But whenever a plane (passenger or sport) or a helicopter (police, rescue...) comes by, I'd like to know it.

Comment: “_the measurements need to work for every aircraft, optional messages only certain aircrafts send are not an option_”. That effectively rules out ADS-B. Even in places where it’s mandatory there are still a number of exceptions, and of course there could be malfunctions. In which country/region are you?

Comment: As jcaron points out, this will not work. If you absolutely need an area completely free of air traffic, you need to work with the local aviation authorities to set up a (temporary) restricted area

Comment: We're talking about germany and I was under the impression that an ADS-B transponder is mandatory nowadays.  How do the authorities or airports know who's currently flying, do they have a different technology? Please also take note of my edit.

Comment: @user3792852 -- just for completeness you might want to google up the regs for gliders (sailplanes).  I'm not sure whether they are required to have transponders and ADS-B out in Germany or not.  Likewise ultralights or microlights.  I do understand that you know you will never cover *all* possibilities, but just something to consider.

Comment: In some airspace classes you can fly without any transponder at all (ADS-B or otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

A certified and correctly functioning ADS-B transmitter sends position,  (usually GPS derived), pressure altitude and geometric height above WGS84 ellipsoid.

If you know your receiver's position and height (above ellipsoid, not MSL) and you can get the geometric height from ADS-B, then it is easy to solve your problem.

The geometric height is normally encoded as difference from pressure altitude. It is contained in the velocity messages. See EUROCAE ED102A or RTCA DO-260B for encoding details.

**But beware!** Many aircraft in German lower airspace are not equiped with ADS-B transmitters, and those that are equiped may not perform as advertised. Notable examples of non ADS-B aircraft are part of the Medical Helicopter and Police fleet, and those can be expected to fly low and fast.

Don't think that because you have an ADS-B receiver you can fly drones safely and legally. Flying autonomous drones is not allowed in Germany, as far as I know. Look at Germany's DIgital Platform for Unmanned aviation [DIPUL](https://www.dipul.de) for more information about regulations and maps of geozones.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, horizontal distance can be easily deduced from ADS-B messages.

ADS-B can use multiple different sources for position. If it's using GNSS (as most are), it should be transmitting its geometric altitude in addition to its barometric altitude. If it is using DME/DME, for instance, it will not report geometric altitude.

Your options for barometric altitude are to integrate a barometer or to do the same thing airplanes do and get a local altimeter setting. This could be done manually with a handheld radio or automatically if local METARs are available online.

Using both altitudes and taking the closest one is the most conservative approach. If only using one, you should use the barometric altitude and correct for non-standard pressure.

Keep in mind that Europe does not mandate ADS-B for light aircraft flying VFR, which are the aircraft most likely to be so low! So you *absolutely cannot* rely on ADS-B as your sole source of manned aircraft avoidance.